# Identifying peak traffic using Datadog

Tags: datadog

For one of the load tests, I need to identify the peak traffic to an API for a 30 minutes duration in production. I am trying to use the "Query Value" graph type with the below metric query in **Datadog** to get it:
sum:trace.servlet.request.hits{env:production,service:my-api}.as_count().rollup(max, 1800)
Is this the correct approach to get this data from DataDog?
When I try to validate this output against the "Timeseries" graph for the past 1 day duration, it is not matching.

Comment: Are you also using a rollup for the past day's time series? You could be seeing differences due to the [time aggregation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/#time-aggregation) defaulting to an average and longer timeframes having less granular data.

Comment: @EricAllen: yes, I am using "Query Value" to display single value so that the time aggregation would not be an issue but my understanding seems to be wrong.